# flash context in spring 2.5

Tags: spring-mvc

How do i use the flash context in spring without having to install webflow?

Comment: "flash" scope is just a WebFlow thing. Spring doesn't know anything about it.

Comment: bah, grails knows about flash. i like flash and being flashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [mvc-showcase](https://anonsvn.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase/) example you can find special filter which emulates flash scope behaviour, so probably you can use it right now and don't waiting 3.1 with official support.

See for details: [web.xml](https://anonsvn.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml), [FlashMapFilter](https://anonsvn.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/flash/FlashMapFilter.java), [FlashMap](https://anonsvn.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/flash/FlashMap.java)

(I know that mvc-showcase is for Spring 3.0 and you asked about 2.5, but when I look into FlashMapFilter source I see than there no 3.0 specific things.)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`@SessionAttributes` can be used like a flash context, since you can clear them using `SessionStatus`